# Error Inconsistent accessibility - C#

Tags: c#, public, access-modifiers

sorry for my bad english in advance.I'm making a game for a proyect in uni and got stuck in this part where i have to save all the player names per game in a collection. So i got these two classes

```
class Score
{
 ...
}
class ScoreList
{
  public List<Score> NamesList = new List<Score>();

  public ScoreList()
    {}
  public void addScorePlayers(string nom1, string nom2)
  {
    Score part = new Score(player1, player2);
    NamesList.Add(part);
  }
}
```

Then i create an object from the class in a form

```
public partial class FormCreateScoreList : Form
{
    public static ScoreList Names = new ScoreList();
    .....
    .....
}
```

Then in another form i add the name of the two players to the ScoreList

```
public partial class FormCreateScoreScreen : Form
{
  FormCreateScoreList.obj.addScorePlayers("Player1","Player2")
}
```

But when i debug, an error shows up saying

```
  "Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'FinalProject.ScoreList' is less accessible than method 'FinalProject.FormCreateScoreList.Names'"
```

Please help, i don't know how to use a method from an object i've created in form on another form

Answer (score 5):

Your `FormCreateScoreList` is public class yet your `ScoreList` is internal (default accessibility). Change your `ScoreList` to public (`Score` has to be changed as well to public).